# Javascript reduce method for object

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

Now I'm learning about reduce of Javascript. In below code, I don't understand  `acc[key]` because we can access to properties of objects by using `acc["key"]` or `acc.key`  . That's what I learned.
but obviously the code below works correctly..why?

```
const arr = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Cat']
const result = arr.reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (key in acc) {
        acc[key]++
    } else {
        acc[key] = 1
    }
    return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
// { Cat: 2, Dog: 1, Bird: 1 }
```

Comment: `key` is a **string** variable, so if its value is `"Cat"`, `acc[key]` is equivalent to write `acc["Cat"]` or `acc.Cat`.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @Alexandro mentioned that `key` is a string, indeed it is the value or values of the array `arr` which their type is string.  Moreover We know that to access values of an object we follow two ways either **square notation** (e.g. `arr[key]`) or **dot notation** (e.g. `arr.key`). We perfer to use square notation in case there is a key made or contains space or other special chars.

Comment: Thank you so much. I watched several tutorials about reduce method using arr[key]. It's always using arr[key] instead of arr.key and I was wondering why. Your explanation helps my understanding a lot . Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome, happy coding ;)